# Editing CSS from Customized drupal site

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7

I hired some developers, and they did a semi decent job with one of my websites.

However, its still full of errors and poor design.

This is what they designed:

I feel like I did a better job with my "pre launch" lander:

So I think (with a lot of guesswork) I'm a better designer than these guys. The problem is that I don't know how drupal works.

I'm trying to figure out how the CSS works and I got 16 CSS files.

They are so unresponsive it drives me insane. The site has been like this for almost a month.. 95% completed, but not quite. If you make your window smaller for example, the register will overlap on the login. I would know how to fix it, but not on this drupal platform.

Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered hiring someone else? There are quite a few issues you are trying to address in one question. If you really want to try this on your own, you should probably look into a course on CSS. Maybe check out udemy or lynda.

Comment: Is this the finished product that they supplied you with? If so I would have to say that they have done an extremely poor job. As they say, you get what you pay for. The cheapest options is usually not the best option, especially when it comes to development. I agree with the post above, either hire a decent drupal developer or actually learn drupal yourself.